# Flutter show confirmation pop up before exiting from app

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to take confirmation from user before leaving the app, ideally when clicked on default system back navigation button and at time my navigation stack is empty. 
Suppose I am on my homepage after login, and when I try to go back instead of returning me to login page it should show a pop up dialog. And based on the selection either close the app or leave it open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap your home screen widget with `WillPopScope` widget and inside `onWillPop` callback write show your dialog and take action based on user's choice